# Passing a function that accepts class member functions as variables into python multiprocess pool.map()

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Hi I've been struggling with this for the better part of the morning and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
def f(tup):
    return some_complex_function(*tup)

def main():

    pool = Pool(processes=4) 
    #import and process data omitted 
    _args = [(x.some_func1, .05, x.some_func2) for x in list_of_some_class]
    results = pool.map(f, _args)
    print results
```

The first error I get is:

```
> Exception in thread Thread-2: Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
>     self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
>     self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 319, in
> _handle_tasks
>     put(task) PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `multiprocess` module uses the `pickle` module to serialize the arguments passed to the function (`f`), which is executed in another process.

Many of the built-in types can be pickled, but instance methods cannot be pickled. So `.05` is fine, but `x.some_func1` isn't. See [What can be pickled and unpickled?](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) for more details.

There's no simple solution. You'll need to restructure your program so instance methods don't need to be passed as arguments (or avoid using `multiprocess`).

Comment: Thanks took your suggesting and restructured

Answer (score 3):

If you use a fork of `multiprocessing` called `pathos.multiprocesssing`, you can directly use classes and class methods in multiprocessing's `map` functions.  This is because `dill` is used instead of `pickle` or `cPickle`, and `dill` can serialize almost anything in python.

`pathos.multiprocessing` also provides an asynchronous map function… and it can `map` functions with multiple arguments (e.g. `map(math.pow, [1,2,3], [4,5,6])`)

See:
[What can multiprocessing and dill do together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984152/what-can-multiprocessing-and-dill-do-together)

and:
http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2013/12/05/Parallelism-and-Serialization/

```
>>> from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
>>> 
>>> p = Pool(4)
>>> 
>>> def add(x,y):
...   return x+y
... 
>>> x = [0,1,2,3]
>>> y = [4,5,6,7]
>>> 
>>> p.map(add, x, y)
[4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> 
>>> class Test(object):
...   def plus(self, x, y): 
...     return x+y
... 
>>> t = Test()
>>> 
>>> p.map(Test.plus, [t]*4, x, y)
[4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> 
>>> p.map(t.plus, x, y)
[4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Get the code here:
 https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos