# multiprocessing -> pathos.multiprocessing and windows

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, dill, pathos

I'm currently using the standard multiprocessing in python to generate a bunch of processes that will run indefinitely. I'm not particularly concerned with performance; each thread is simply watching for a different change on the filesystem, and will take the appropriate action when a file is modified.

Currently, I have a solution that works, for my needs, in Linux. I have a dictionary of functions and arguments that looks like:

```
 job_dict['func1'] = {'target': func1, 'args': (args,)}
```

For each, I create a process:

```
 import multiprocessing
 for k in job_dict.keys():
     jobs[k] = multiprocessing.Process(target=job_dict[k]['target'],
                                       args=job_dict[k]['args'])
```

With this, I can keep track of each one that is running, and, if necessary, restart a job that crashes for any reason.

This does not work in Windows. Many of the functions I'm using are wrappers, using various `functools` functions, and I get messages about not being able to serialize the functions (see [What can multiprocessing and dill do together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984152/what-can-multiprocessing-and-dill-do-together)). I have not figured out why I do not get this error in Linux, but do in Windows.

If I import `dill` before starting my processes in Windows, I do not get the serialization error. However, the processes do not actually do anything. I cannot figure out why.

I then switched to the multiprocessing implementation in `pathos`, but did not find an analog to the simple `Process` class within the standard `multiprocessing` module. I was able to generate threads for each job using `pathos.pools.ThreadPool`. This is not the intended use for map, I'm sure, but it started all the threads, and they ran in Windows:

```
import pathos
tp = pathos.pools.ThreadPool()
for k in job_dict.keys():
    tp.uimap(job_dict[k]['target'], job_dict[k]['args'])
```

However, now I'm not sure how to monitor whether a thread is still active,  which I'm looking for so that I can restart threads that crash for some reason or another. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm the `pathos` and `dill` author.  The `Process` class is buried deep within `pathos` at `pathos.helpers.mp.process.Process`, where `mp` itself is the actual fork of the `multiprocessing` library.  Everything in `multiprocessing` should be accessible from there.

Another thing to know about `pathos` is that it keeps the `pool` alive for you until you remove it from the held state.  This helps reduce overhead in creating "new" pools.  To remove a pool, you do:

```
>>> # create
>>> p = pathos.pools.ProcessPool()
>>> # remove
>>> p.clear()
```

There's no such mechanism for a `Process` however.

For `multiprocessing`, windows is different than Linux and Macintosh… because windows doesn't have a proper `fork` like on linux…  linux can share objects across processes, while on windows there is no sharing… it's basically a fully independent new process created… and therefore the serialization has to be better for the object to pass across to the other process -- just as if you would send the object to another computer.  On, linux, you'd have to do this to get the same behavior:

```
def check(obj, *args, **kwds):
    """check pickling of an object across another process"""
    import subprocess
    fail = True
    try:
        _x = dill.dumps(x, *args, **kwds)
        fail = False
    finally:
        if fail:
            print "DUMP FAILED"
    msg = "python -c import dill; print dill.loads(%s)" % repr(_x)
    print "SUCCESS" if not subprocess.call(msg.split(None,2)) else "LOAD FAILED"
```

Comment: Thank you. I had read you describe pathos as a fork of the multiprocessing library, and had looked for it in pathos, but had not noticed it tucked inside helpers. I also appreciate the explanation of why multiprocessing behaves differently in windows and linux. I replaced my mutliprocessing.Process calls with ones from pathos, but got the same behavior as when I imported dill before the call with the standard multiprocessing. I'm going to keep playing with it, but may also re-evaluate the way I'm approaching this problem more generally.

Comment: the reason you got the same behavior when using `multiprocessing` and first importing `dill`, is that `dill` can override **python** `pickle`, but `multiprocessing` uses **C-python** `pickle`… so it has to be forked to use `dill`.

Comment: …and maybe I have the fork buried too deeply.  However, it is available as a standalone package called `multiprocess`.  I'll have to think about whether it makes sense to bubble it up in `pathos` a little bit more or not.